# xcode printing <meta> tag when not needed

Tags: php, iphone, ios, web-services

I'm coding in xcode and I'm using a phpscript to get information from my database.

I've a phpScript looking like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<?php

    echo "你好";


?>
```

The problem is, when I try to print it out in the xcode using NSLog.

it prints this in the console which i do not want:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
你好
```

It's supposed to just show:

```
你好
```

I'm using these codes in xcode to get the information:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.???.com/getcountry.php"];

// to execute php code
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

// to receive the returend value
NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Please advise, thank you.

Comment: What does this have to do with Xcode? It sounds like your script itself is emitting the `<meta>` tag. What happens if you remove that like from your PHP script?

Comment: I see what you mean. The meta tag is used so the browser understands the chinese character. If I make do without it, it will show gibberish. I'm in quite a dilemma.

Comment: The console is not a browser; it'll print HTML as if it were plain text, causing your meta tag to show up. Did you mean to run your PHP script in a web view instead?

Comment: I meant it as a background thing to run on the console, not on a web view. Do you have any solutions as to how I can overcome this issue?

Comment: Can we see the Objective-C code you're using to run the script? It's currently not clear how you're running the script and in what context. Is this a web service with an iPhone app as the client (judging from the tags)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all your app is doing is fetching the content being sent by your script, it treats your HTML meta tag as if it were normal text. That's why it shows up in the console in plain text. But if you're not interested in outputting HTML, you don't actually need the meta tag.

If you only really need the script to say `你好`, simply remove the meta tag from your PHP script and just echo that text:

```
<?php echo "你好"; ?>
```